# How to data view like gridview with linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-intent

I have written a code, where ,
A Layout is divided with weightsum.
Every weight contain a linearlayout.

I have a arraylist of string.
I have to put data like....

```
> 1.         2.          3.
> 4.          5.
```

Provide some code or samples.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the question is.... If you want a grid, use a RecyclerView with an Adapter. Adapters do work with ArrayLists, so if that is what you need I'll put some sample code in an answer. In particular, LinearLayout is for Linear Layouts, not Grids.

Comment: Can you help me , disable gridview scroll view?

Comment: How to use linear layout as alternative of gridview?

Comment: did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: remember to accept answers on your questions... If they helped

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html#using-lists-or-grids-in-android

This shows how to create a RecyclerView with an Adapter made of an ArrayList of Strings.

In particular, this is the code you need:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset); //Where myDataset is your ArrayList<String> and MyAdapter is described in depth in the link I provided
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Since you are still asking about LinearLayout, I'll try to clear it up.

You can use LinearLayout to create a single row OR a single column of equal-width Views by using the "layout-width" attribute or programmatically with something like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.weight = 1;

view.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Also, LinearLayout isn't fit for a dynamic list of data, even though you could theoretically loop through your list and use "addView" to create everything manually.